# No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to compile my Project,but in there is some error

Android manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I already try to rebuild project or sync with gradle but it's not working for me.

my dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':circleimageview-2.0.0-sources')
```

How to fix this error? I'm newbie to Android Studio.

Comment: `roundIcon` was [first added in API 25](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#roundIcon), so my guess is that your project is configured to build for an earlier API. Could you post your project-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Simply remove `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`roundIcon` is an attribute that was [first introduced for Android Nougat 7.1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#roundIcon) (API level 25), therefore you have two available options based on the type of device you're targeting:

- If you're building an app specifically for Android 7.1 or above, ensure that `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to 25 in your app's `build.gradle`:

---

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

---

- Alternatively, if you want to target older API levels, you will need to remove `android:roundIcon` from your manifest and only use `android:icon`.

Comment: No worries, if this answer has helped then please upvote and accept.

Comment: Android 7.1 is still N(Nougat).  Android O is 8.0.

Comment: I believe this is a bug with android studio, I specifically created project to compile with API 21 and yet `android:roundIcon` property still added to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Android studio keeps adding roundIcon even after deleting it from manifest resulting in build failure. How to solve this using compileSdkVersion 23 ?

Comment: API 25 is Nougat. 27 is Oreo.

Comment: @IshitaSinha Technically both 26 and 27 are Oreo (8.0 and 8.1 respectively), but yes, my answer was targeting the wrong version. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Well, `roundIcon` was introduced in 25, which is Nougat, not Oreo.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your suggestions saved time for me.

Answer (score 7):

I removed `android:roundIcon` from my manifest, but when compiling my project with API 24, the `android:roundIcon` property is still added to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In order to resolve my problem, I had to update my API to version 25 and set `comileSdkversion` to `25`.

Comment: That's probably because you removed it from the AndroidManifest.xml generated in the target. That the one that will open when you click on the error. You should remove it from the source code (The one you wrote).

Answer (score 0):

roundIcon is an attribute that was first introduced for Android O (8.0). So you have to change the app compile SDK version.

[image: change the compile SDK version]

Comment: it's introduced in Nougat 7.1 (API 25) not in Oreo 8.0 (API 26)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered earlier, roundicon was first introduced in API Level 25. If you want to maintain a lower API level without increasing to >= 25 then

go to the **mipmap** directory and **delete** the subdirectory **"ic_roundicon"** with all its files

[delete @res/mipmap/ic_roundicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAk8F.png)