# Gradle error when sync project in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

any time that i create project in android studio 3 i have problem with gradle sync with errors.

[image]
Message Gradle Build:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
/Applications/Desktop/AndroidProjects/RealmProject/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(11) error: attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.
Error:(11) attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 23s
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

app.gradle module config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammad.realmproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: The issue is here:  attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050318/4345934) ***=>*** `roundIcon` is an attribute that was [first introduced for Android O](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#roundIcon) (8.0, API level 25), therefore you have two available options based on the type of device you're targeting:

- If you're building an app specifically for Android O, ensure that `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to 25 in your app's `build.gradle`:

---

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

---

- Alternatively, if you want to target older API levels, you will need to remove `android:roundIcon` from your manifest and only use `android:icon`.

Comment: API 25 was Nougat Maintenance Release 1, Android 7.1.