# Why does Android Studio throw errors in the manifest file when we change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 26 to 23?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have searched SO thoroughly and couldn't find the reason for the error that I am facing.

**Things I did:**

1. I changed the compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersions in app gradle file from 26 to 23.
2. I clicked sync now.
3. It resulted in 7 error messages making my manifest file go haywire.

**Snippets:**

1. My App Gradle file after changing the compile,target sdk versions to 23 from 26

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 26
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.airtelanalytics"
>         minSdkVersion 14
>         targetSdkVersion 26
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.+'
>     compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-processes:1.1.1'
>     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
> }
> ```

2. Android SDK Platform 23 is installed already

[image: Sdk 23 installed already]

3. Error Messages (affecting Manifest file) due to change of SDK version from 26 to 23

[image: Error Messages]

4. Manifest file

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="14"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:debuggable="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity android:name="com.analyticsdemo.MainActivity" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

How to fix this ?

Comment: please show the application tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: remove android:roundIcon from Android Manifest

Comment: Do not paste Gradle build files and error messages as images. Paste them as *text*. Also, if you are having problems with the manifest, it would help if you posted the manifest, also as text.

Comment: post Mainfest file

Comment: Just now reading the comments, I will post those as code in a minute

Comment: can you please try go File -> Invalidate catches/restart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049734/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-roundicon-in-package-android)

Comment: Its not a duplicate of that question, my question is more broader. The question you are referring to is just one of the 7 errors arouse when I changed the sdk version from 26 to 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I changed the compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersions in app gradle file from 26 to 23.

That is not a good plan, particularly if you plan to ship via the Play Store, as you will [have to raise the values again shortly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/08/android-version-ratchet.html).

> How to fix this ?

The best solution is to move your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` back to 26.

Otherwise, fix the errors reported by the compiler.

In this case, your manifest has `android:roundIcon` on `<application>`, and `android:roundIcon` did not exist back with API Level 23. You are saying, via `compileSdkVersion 23`, that you want to compile using the rules that existed for API Level 23, and that includes not using things that did not exist back then. So, get rid of `android:roundIcon` from your actual manifest.

Comment: Say if I have to create an application which targets only Marshmallow (ver 23), should I uninstall the Oreo or Nougat SDK which is already installed ?

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran: "I have to create an application which targets only Marshmallow (ver 23)" -- since that is not possible, my guess is that you and I are using different terms. "should I uninstall the Oreo or Nougat SDK which is already installed ?" -- that is up to you and is unrelated to your problem.