# Android Studio 3.1.3 android:roundIcon

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have a `Compile Error` telling me to remove `android:roundIcon` from `AndroidManifest.xml`, similar to this other post:
[No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049734/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-roundicon-in-package-android/43050318)

I have targeted `API 15` and only have that version installed, but `Android Studio` keeps re-adding that line and breaking compilation. How do I stop/fix this?

My `build.gradle` has:

```
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.testapplication.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It just keeps re-adding `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` if I delete it. How do I stop that behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to release apps with targetSdk < 26 to the playstore in like a month, so you really should target 26+

Comment: Please add your `manifest.xml` code to question

Comment: I have an old Android 5 tablet that I want to whip up an app for. (I want to see if I can train my cat to press buttons on it.) I don't care about publicly releasing the app. What is most silly is that it compiled once and loaded "Hello World" onto the tablet, but then added that line afterwards and now won't compile at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update  target and compile sdk version to latest api  28  in `build.gradle`  `android:targetSdkVersion="28"`
`"compileSdkVersion 28"`

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all the "@mipmap/ic_launcher" for round icons. You'll be done. Also, if it doesn't solve, try adding your own icon for the same using an image asset and setting it as "ic_launcher" icon.

Comment: Apparently API 25 added that feature. It won't let me delete it. It puts it back. I tried marking the file read only, but that messes up compiling as well. Now I'm digging through project settings to see if I missed anything. I may just tear down the project and start over, since this is just a "getting to know Android Studio" project.

Comment: Did you try deleting it from your "file explorer"? I mean navigate to the file location (mipmap/ic_launcher_round) by right clicking on the file and then "show in explorer". From there you can delete it. Then just clean the project and try again?

Comment: Now AAPT.exe crashes on build. I think I'll get some sleep and resume tinkering in the morning. Thanks for the suggestions.