# I can't delete android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

i build a project with **targetSdkVersion="22"**
but the error is come

```
error: attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.
```

i tried with deleting `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` at `AndroidManifest.xml` but it reappears if i try to build again.
then i tried to delete ic_launcher_round at mipmap directory but the error is still same and the code is still reappears.

Comment: try cleaning the project and rebuild.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049734/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-roundicon-in-package-android)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049734/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-roundicon-in-package-android/43050318

Comment: @Aslam i do, but it still reappears,

Comment: @Kushan i try to remove the code, and remove the ic_launcher directory at mipmap becuse of that post, but the code is still reappears, i'm sorry about duplicate post

Comment: It shouldn't reappear (unless you are deleting in generated resources). I am wondering why you are still using targetSdkVersion="22"

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i just downloaded that version, bcs i have not enough connection to download others again XD, i'm sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably editing one of the *cached* `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

Make sure you edit the file in your project. I.e. Look carefully on the path when you open the file. Is it part of your project or some *generated* stuff?

Comment: oh my god, how fool i am XD,

now i got new error msg,
error: attribute 'android:endX' not found.
error: attribute 'android:endY' not found.
and others

Comment: @ahmadbahruddin this is a separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i just want to know if it just simple problem that i doesn't know how to resolve or no, if its just simple i think i didn't need to make a question again. if its not maybe i'll consider to make another question. thank you