# Problem with Google Play Console and upload of APK

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload my APK to Google Play Console. The translation of the red text roughly says that version 1 is used already. This is from `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.010">
```

[image: Screenshot of Google Play Console]

Anyone?

Comment: double check your gradle files that your version code is not correct

Comment: Thanks Yasiru. But shouln't that file be updated automatically?

Comment: I think you should always use the gradle files when changing version names or version codes

Comment: Ok, thanks again Yasiru :-)

Answer (score 0):

Under app in the top root directory for your apps tree in Android Studio, edit bulid.gradle. For some reason AndroidManifest.xml is ignored when it coems to versioning.

Comment: For sure, the `gradle` setting will overwrite the `xml` value. However, a common mistake is to edit a cached version of the manifest. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57610125/419761).